# Terminal says 'Read-only file system' after trying to force RGB mode for my display

Tags: terminal, display, root, big-sur

I'm trying to force RGB mode in macOS to fix the picture quality of my external monitor. I had to do this when I got my MacBook 16". Now, after installing Big Sur, the problem reappears.

The instructions I've followed are:

1. Run:

   ```
   csrutil disable
   ```

   in recovery mode in order to disable rootless mode.
2. Run the following patch:

   ```
   patch-edid.rb
   ```

   and then do the following:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/DisplayVendorID-472
   sudo cp DisplayProductID-361 /System/Library/Displays/Contents/Resources/Overrides/DisplayVendorID-472
   ```

but Terminal returns this error: `'read-only' file system`

I tried the following:

```
mount -o remount /
```

But Terminal fails with this error: `mount: / failed with 64`

Comment: I believe Big Sur has an extra layer of security when it comes to system files/root that requires a few extra steps beyond just disabling SIP. However, I can't advise you how to do it, as I am waiting for some examples before I do it myself. You can search up about Signed System Volume (SSV) that Apple has introduced in Big Sur.

Comment: Make sure you have a backup before moving forward, and also verify whether the patch is valid for Big Sur.